# How to align text properly in the next line using css

Tags: css

I am trying to fix alignment issue for a tag text. I have given margin-left: 100px; for the text.But the next line text is not coming properly. Thenext line text is not taking the margin left value.How to fix this.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/myshfnxd/6/

HTML:

```
    <a href="" class="simpletxt">
<span class="subtext">Text1</span><span>Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.simpletxt {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: 100px;
   width: auto;
   height: 100px;
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
   word-wrap: break-word;
}

.subtext{
  float:left;
}
```

Expecting like this:

[image]

But getting like this:

[image]

Comment: a is an inline element, so set a as display:inline-block and set width:auto;

Comment: @Sfili_81: Not working

Comment: a possible [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/86masfy7/1/), n.B. fixed width is only for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use grid template as below:

```
<a href="" class="simpletxt">
    <span class="col-1">Text1</span>
    <span class="col-2"> Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2 </span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.simpletxt {
    max-width: 400px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```css
.simpletxt {
  max-width: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.col-2{
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="simpletxt">
  <span class="col-1">Text1</span>
  <span class="col-2"> Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2Text2 </span>
</a>
```